# Link List pointer's position(index) troubles

Tags: c, pointers, indexing, while-loop

```
Status ListDelete(LinkList *L, int i, int *e)
{
   int j=0;
   LinkList p=L,q;
   while(p->next && j > i-1)
   {
     p = p->next;
     j++;
   }

   if(!p->next||j>i-1) 
     return ERROR;
   q=p->next; 
   p->next=q->next;
   *e=q->data;
   free(q);
   return OK;
}
```

the code is correct, but I need some explanation on the position change of the pointer p.
My question is: 
if I want to delete the second`(i=2)` element in the linklist, then the condition in `while()` for the first time should be `(j<i-1 => 0<2-1)`, so actually, the while only execute once, but the p in the while loop already points to the second element, so I believe `q->next` should points to the third element.
When I execute the code, it works well, if the input `i = 2`, it will delete the second element, but in my understanding, it should delete the third element. Why?

Comment: `LinkList p=L` -> `LinkList *p=L`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the loop condition tells the code how many elements the loop must *skip* before the deletion. When you need to delete the second element, you need to skip one element ahead of it. In general, to delete element number N, you need to skip N-1 elements.

Comment: I missed one important condition, this linklist has a header element. so the third position should contain the second element.

Comment: @albert This makes sense: that is why the code deletes `q`, which is set to `q=p->next`, and not `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the i-1, which makes i = 1, which points to the second element in the list. HTH.